# Equivalent of the Third Isomorphism Theorem (Modules)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I saw this problem in Rotman's textbook:

[image]

I can do this problem but I did not follow the hint since I don't see how the hints help us here.  Another question I have is that this problem said it's another version of the Third Isomorphism Theorem for modules but I don't see the equivalencies between these two. Can anyone point this out for me?

Thank you very much.